# "Walking " through file making changes, PHP

Tags: php, fgetc

I want to replace each character in file with another one by one "walk" through the file.

It is like using fgetc(), but I also need to replace that char. 
My file is big, which is the best way to do this? Any advice?

Comment: Create a temporary file. Write replaced characters to a memory buffer, write said buffer to the temp file periodically. When you're done, remove the old file and rename the new one.

Comment: the main reason is that I don\t want to you use anything like: find and replace, I don't want to search the document... because, anyways I have to replace every character in file, why should I search? If I will search, then I wil have to  "walk" through the document for every letter I'm searching, that's gonna be n times loop, where n is the number of elements of alphabet...
So, I'm looking for way to solve this problem by one "walk", only one.. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you're a Linux user look into the use of `sed`. There are alternatives for windows that allow you to do it as well but you'll need to download them (they're not default)

It works like this: say you have a sentence "Hello World". Run the command:

```
sed s/l/p/g sentence.txt
```

You get the output: "Heppo Worpd" (replacing all l's with p's).

Comment: If this is applicable, the `-i` flag (replace input file contents) might come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

fopen mode c+ should do what you want. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php